# How to save an NSDictionary with NSValue objects to a file

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a flat NSDictionary with keys as NSNumber objects and values as NSValue objects. How do I save this to a file?

I've tried writing the dictionary directly to a file and also archiving to NSData but both fail.

```
// Try 1: Archive
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];

// Try 2: Write to file
[dictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

The NSValue objects contain string pointers.

```
[NSValue valueWithPointerString:text];
```

Comment: Why do you use `NSValue` to encapsulate `NSString` objects? Do you have an error? What about using `writeToFile:options:error:` to get a more explicit error (rather than a bool ?)

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a property list but then you need to replace the NSNumber keys with e.g. strings and the NSValue objects must be 'part of the family'. This is a good option if you can get past these requirements and you should give it serious consideration.

Then you can load with

```
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL...
```

and save with

```
[dict writeToUrl...
```

which is nice and easy and without the complexities of today's NSSecureCoding.

Otherwise you need to delve into keyed archiver and ensure the keys and objects all implement NSCoding / NSSecureCoding. Even here it can quickly become quite a mission but is the 'normal' route for a dictionary with custom objects. Edit: If you use NSString and NSNumber you should not have trouble.

However, if you have custom objects e.g. your values are some weird thing that does not implement NSCoding then you must consult the *Archives and Serializations Programming Guide* in the docs. You can go there anyhow for any of these options, but maybe easiest for now is the first one?